# Adding data to hyperlink dynamically on click of another button by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor with id='peter'. When i click this, the hyperlink of anchor 'jack' must now add the id of 'peter' at the end of its hyperlink.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#peter').click(function(){
              $('#jack').attr('href', '?id=peter');
           });
       });
    </script>
  </head>

<body> 
<a href="" id="peter">Click</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="jack">Yahoo</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Expectation:

> the hyperlink of second anchor must now be -
>   http://www.yahoo.com?id=peter

Can someone help me out how to add this id by 'jQuery'?

Comment: Have you try to get `href` value first and after do `$('#jack').attr('href', href_value+'?id=peter');`  you can get `href value` by `$('#jack').attr('href');` @Peterson

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suvzw2nv/

Comment: Well, I`ve tried to answer and they voted me down as I`ve said something wrong or bad... I guess this is the way stackoverflow works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your existing javascript code with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#peter').click(function(){
      var attr = $('#jack').attr('href') + "?id=peter";
        $('#jack').attr('href', attr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to **append** param to the `href` attribute:

```
var href = $('#jack').attr('href');
$('#jack').attr('href', href + '?id=peter');
```

Answer (score -1):

One way can be to replace the href attribute:
 $('#jack').attr('href', 'http://www.yahoo.com?id=peter');

Another option is to add it at the end of the current value:

```
var href = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
$('#jack').attr('href', href + '?id=peter');
```